# Why are top level methods handled differently in irb?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, irb

Considering this code:

```
def x; end
puts public_methods.include? :x
```

if I run it on `irb` and the ruby interpreter (both using Ruby 1.9.3) I get:

```
true # from irb
false # from ruby
```

Why are top-level methods defined publicly in `irb` and why does it differ from `ruby`?

[image: irb session]

Comment: Irb gives `false` in my environment.

Comment: irb gives false in my environment, too.

Comment: I too get false in irb

Comment: I've added a photo showing the actual irb session.

Comment: This behaviour changed in Ruby 2.0.0. Both irb/ruby yield `false` in Ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this behavior in Ruby 1.9.3p448.

I think it's because in irb's repl the definitions are wrapped in singleton, so to imitate it just put following in your script:

```
class << self
  def x; end
end

puts public_methods.member? :x    # true
```